# MySQL UPDATE: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

The following query in MySQL:

```
UPDATE e_element e1
 INNER JOIN
 (
 SELECT DVAL
 FROM e1
  INNER JOIN  e_element e2
   ON e1.ENT_OID = e2.ENT_OID
  WHERE
   e2.META_OID = 336810 AND
   e1.META_OID = 359462 AND
   e1.DVAL = '0001-01-01 00:00:00'
 )
SET e1.DVAL = e2.DVAL;
```

Throws the following error:

```
Error Code: 1248
Every derived table must have its own alias
```

I have tried a few different options with two select statements but I can never achieved the result I want which is to copy the value from e2 to e1 given those conditions

Comment: Remove bracket `}` and replace with closing bracket `)`.

Comment: There is no `}` in the code you posted, because you replaced it with `)`. But running the updated query doesn't produce the reported error any more. Either update the error message (if you still get one) or close the question because in its current state it's not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has multiple errors . . . a curly brace, no `on` clause, an inappropriate reference to a table alias, a `where` clause in the wrong place.

Perhaps you intend:

```
UPDATE e_element e1 INNER JOIN
       e_element e2
       ON e1.ENT_OID = e2.ENT_OID
    SET e1.DVAL = e2.DVAL
WHERE e2.META_OID = 336810 AND
      e1.META_OID = 359462 AND
      e1.DVAL = '0001-01-01 00:00:00';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
UPDATE e_element e1 
  INNER JOIN e_element e2
       ON e1.ENT_OID = e2.ENT_OID
    SET e1.DVAL = e2.DVAL
WHERE e2.META_OID = 336810 
      AND e1.META_OID = 359462 
      AND e1.DVAL = '0001-01-01 00:00:00';
```

Hope this would help you out.